# i, c = 0, len(arr) почему здесь нельзя обойтись без len(arr)?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def iZ (arr) :
    i, c = 0, len(arr)  # какая роль тут у len(arr) ? зачем оно здесь?
    while i < c :
        arr[i] += 2
        i += 1
    print(arr)
```

Почему если оставить только i, c = 0 вылезает ошибка? И почему тут не обойтись без len(arr)?

Comment: почему же нельзя? `arr[:] = [x+2 for x in arr]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потому, что это две инструкции присваивания

```
i = 0
c = len(arr)
```

записанные в одну строку. Во второй переменной `c` присваивается длина массива `arr`. А в следующей строке начинается цикл до тех пор, пока значение `i` меньше значения `c`. Если оба значения будут равны 0, цикл не выполнится.